What happened to JacksonJaxbJsonProvider class in 2.16.x onwards?
Whilst migrating for Jakarta.x related mess, I realised that JacksonJaxbJsonProvider class was dropped (at least from 2.16.x version onwards).
This is the multi-module repo - https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jakarta-rs-providers
And the class is now gone.
Does anyone know what the best replacement option is for these classes. And apologies again if I missed any obvious note in the release sections.
I will be revisiting the notes again before checking this SO thread.

That class - as far as I know - never existed in jackson-jakarta-rs-providers (or actually jackson-jakarta-rs-json-provider) under that name, only in jackson-jaxrs-providers (jackson-jaxrs-json-provider).
Its replacement when the Jakarta EE variant was created, was named com.fasterxml.jackson.jakarta.rs.json.JacksonXmlBindJsonProvider (for comparison, see the "old" javax JacksonJaxbJsonProvider documentation)

The first version of this answer had a copy/paste error, the new class name is com.fasterxml.jackson.jakarta.rs.json.JacksonXmlBindJsonProvider (and not com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider as I had in the initial version). I'm posting this comment to call it out more specifically, as my edits to the answer might not notify you

thanks nice one! I didn't think of checking the file history.

In addition to the answer provided by @MarkRotteveel above.

See the attached comparison between the two files - they are functionally identical.

If you are using rudimentary stuff JacksonJsonProvider should be sufficient for you.



